# segmentation fault (core dumped) using glib.h

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glib

I crushed with the error segmentation fault (core dumped) while compiling my code.. can you help me with that?
I'm using glib.h for the first time, I think my error is in that part of code. while using pointers in Ghash.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <glib.h>

char filename[] = "blacklist";

char *t = filename;

FILE * fi;
FILE * fi2;
FILE * fo;

GHashTable *hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash,g_str_equal);

void load_domain_black_list(char *t)
{
    fi = fopen(t,"r");
    char *s;
    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(fi,"%s",s);

        if(feof(fi)>0) break;

        g_hash_table_add(hash,s);
    }
    fclose(fi);
}

int check_domain_blacklist(char *domain)
{
    return g_hash_table_contains(hash,domain);
}

main()
{
    fi2 = fopen("domains_for_check","r");
    fo = fopen("result","w");

    load_domain_black_list(t);

    char *domain;

    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(fi2,"%s",domain);

        if(feof(fi2)>0)
            break;

        fprintf(fo,"%d",check_domain_blacklist(domain));
    }

    fclose(fi2);
    fclose(fo);
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `s` before using it with `fscanf`.

Comment: And the same thing with `domain` in `main()`.

Comment: You always need to initialize your pointers. Your not pointing to anything and then you try to read in a value to it. Not possible

Comment: can you explain more? will i initialize them like s=0?

Comment: i got it thx a lot